# How to get average from each hour in one week in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a task to get the average some data in each hour inside a week.

```
{'hour': 0, 'count': 70}
{'hour': 1, 'count': 92}
{'hour': 2, 'count': 94}
{'hour': 3, 'count': 88}
{'hour': 4, 'count': 68}
{'hour': 5, 'count': 69}
{'hour': 6, 'count': 70}
{'hour': 7, 'count': 82}
{'hour': 8, 'count': 91}
{'hour': 9, 'count': 67}
{'hour': 10, 'count': 92}
{'hour': 11, 'count': 100}
{'hour': 12, 'count': 92}
{'hour': 13, 'count': 55}
{'hour': 14, 'count': 61}
{'hour': 15, 'count': 47}
{'hour': 16, 'count': 36}
{'hour': 17, 'count': 19}
{'hour': 18, 'count': 11}
{'hour': 19, 'count': 6}
{'hour': 20, 'count': 3}
{'hour': 21, 'count': 9}
{'hour': 22, 'count': 27}
{'hour': 23, 'count': 47}
```

The data above is the result of this query

```
result = Device.objects.filter(station__in=stations, created_at__range=(start_date, end_date)) \
            .extra({'hour': 'hour(created_at)'}) \
            .values('hour').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by('hour')
```

the result is queryed by 7 days range, what I want to do is get the average for each hour in 7 days, exampe the total of count in hour 0 is 70 then i need to average it from 7 days.

Any suggestion?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68022/113740

Comment: @DeepakMahakale it's not related to what i need, any suggestion to do it with django orm?

Comment: not exactly, 

but you will have to use the average function on the extracted hour from the date and group them by hours.

Try to convert the same in django orm

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can try like this with [**`F()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expression:

```
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper, DecimalField    

result = result.annotate(average=ExpressionWrapper(F('count')/7, output_field=DecimalField()))
```